# Get data from two tables that have a joining table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, left-join, outer-join

im sorry im asking this.  im not sure why i cant get it.  i guess im still new.

i have three tables as so:

```
ITEM
item_id
item_name

LOCATION 
location_id
location_name

ITEM_LOCATION
item_id FK
location_id FK
```

my query is:

```
SELECT item.item_name, location.location_name 
FROM item
LEFT OUTER JOIN item_location 
    ON item_location.item_id = item.item_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN location
    ON location.location_id = item_location.location_id
WHERE item.item_id = 1
```

i get a value for item name, i do not get a value for location_name, even though the relationship is there on the join table.  I would have thought this would return a value for both based on the relationship

Comment: Your data doesn't link up properly.  If you think it is, put a sample of data up on SQL Fiddle so we can see what is happening.

Comment: ive never used sql fiddle.  but i could see a problem i just thought of... if i select * from item_location it returns the relationship of 1 and 4.  but thats the only row on the table atm.  but if i add the location_id of 4 to the where clause, it doesnt return anything

Comment: my data was not linked correctly, sorry, its been a long day.  thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Just a pet peeve of mine, if you join table a to b to c when put the join expression as b.id = a.id.  Just does not make sense.  The parser does not care, but logically it is back wards!

Answer (score 0):

why you are using `LEFT OUTER JOIN` ?

Try this instead:

> SELECT item.item_name, location.location_name
>     FROM item
>   INNER JOIN item_location
>       ON item_location.item_id = item.item_id
>   INNER JOIN location
>       ON location.location_id = item_location.location_id
>   WHERE item.item_id = 1

Comment: the inner join returns nothing.  with my query im at least getting the item name

Comment: @user2070677 That means that your data is not linked as suggested by Gordon.

Comment: it wasnt.  sorry to waste time

Comment: yeah if you get nothing, that means that you are probably missing rows in your relation table (item_location)